# React Native - Unable to create text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a text input element but the it keeps throwing out error saying "Can't Find Variable: TextInput" even though I copied the code from their getting started page.

Code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            My App Name
        </Text>
        <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({input: text})}
        />
  <Text>{'user input: ' + this.state.input}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

and the image of error attached. [image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to initialize TextInput with the rest of the react-native components as follows:

```
var {
  TextInput,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
```

Comment: Just to add onto this: if you've forgotten to import TextInput in another file (say AnotherThing.js) that's imported into App.js, the error will look like it's coming from App.js even if it's coming from AnotherThing.js

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. What I did! I deleted the `node-module`, And run `npm install` or `yarn install`. Then the issue was resolved. You can try it.